# Internal error when running visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, system.reflection

I'm building a WPF application that currently only has UI elements in place. I'm trying to use some classes I made in another project by importing a dll. When I run the wpf application, Visual Studio pops up this dialog in the Team Explorer:

[image: error message]

The application still runs, but I don't know the cause of this error and what its effects are. Has anyone else run into this error and have some insight?

Not sure if it is relevant, but the project I'm importing is using NHibernate and Log4Net. I'm also using Visual Studio 2013 Express if that has anything to do with it.

UPDATE:

Here's the stack trace:

```
   at DatabaseUI.DatabaseViewModel..ctor() in c:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DatabaseUI\DatabaseUI\ViewModels\DatabaseViewModel.cs:line 36
   at DatabaseUI.MainWindow..ctor() in c:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DatabaseUI\DatabaseUI\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 30
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstanceCritical(Type type, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance(Object[] arguments)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(XamlMember property)
   at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at DatabaseUI.App.Main() in c:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DatabaseUI\DatabaseUI\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

UPDATE 2:
I removed the ViewModel code because this problem existed before I created it. I got this error when I first created a wpf application without any content. I'm looking for answers that describe what this error means or a similar situation that someone had where they were able to resolve this issue.

UPDATE 3:
I started a new console application project and I'm getting the same error. This project does not use any resources from the previously described project, but both of these projects use log4net and nhibernate. I think this is an nhibernate issue.

UPDATE 4:
I started a new console application with absolutely nothing to it, and I'm still getting this error. I've deleted all references and the entire AssemblyInfo.cs, and still no progress.

UPDATE 5:
I create a new C++ console application and I am getting the same error. No nhibernate or anything that I thought was messing it up. There is definitely something wrong with Visual Studio...

Comment: HandyPete, In the dll's solution could you create a test project there and instantiate some of the classes in that project. Be interesting to see if the error appears in it when it is run. That might give some level of isolation where the error may be occurring.

Comment: Someone is using reflection and doing wild/wrong casts. You (we all) need the full stack trace. It's almost impossible to help w/o it.

Comment: @Jim I started this project by build a console application that implemented those classes, then took those classes and made the dll. They did not cause errors in the console application, but that was a good idea to try.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'll work on getting you all a full stack trace.

Comment: Please confirm that the line number in the stack trace reflects the actual line number in the file you've shown. I.e. the exception occurs on the last line of the `DatabaseViewModel` constructor. It appears that there is code somewhere, possibly injected by one of those libraries you're using, that is trying to cast a `ConstructorInfo` object found in the stack trace to a `RuntimeMethodInfo` object (a class that isn't even public). Without _complete_ stack track and [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), an answer is unlikely.

Comment: DatabaseViewModel.cs:line 36, why not try commenting out the line System.IO.File.WriteAllText("myTrace.txt"... And see if you still get error?

Comment: @Darren That's what I used to get the stack trace. The error was before that.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out all the code in `DatabaseViewModel` to see if you get the same error? If not, you could uncomment then one at a time to find out what one is causing the problem.

Comment: @Rachel Good point, but I actually had this error right away before I added the DatabaseViewModel. I should have thought of that sooner. I'll remove the ViewModel code from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Do you have the same Stack Trace if you run the application without the DatabaseViewModel? It shows the error as happening in there. Also I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the style of that error message image you uploaded is not one I recognize. Where is that displayed in Visual Studio?

Comment: The error is display in the Team Explorer.

Comment: Can you copy a full reproducing project somewhere? It looks like the XAML parser doesn't like what you feed it with.

Comment: Try removing or disabling all Visual Studio extensions (add-ins). Some of them might be causing Team Explorer to emit errors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed the error by re-installing Visual Studio. I'm still looking into what exactly went wrong, but something deep in the depths of Visual Studio must have been corrupted. Once I know more, I will update this answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have a static resource, in your case is databseviewmodel that is getting initiated and failure is due to that. If your viewmodel is calling database when it is constructed then it will show error due to improper initialization.

Comment: The error happened before the view model was created